# Adding backslashes without escaping

Tags: python, string, replace, escaping

I need to escape a `&` (ampersand) character in a string. The problem is whenever I `string = string.replace ('&', '\&')` the result is `'\\&'`. An extra backslash is added to escape the original backslash. How do I remove this extra backslash?

Comment: Knowing zilch about python: string = string.replace('&', '&') ... maybe the replace method will escape that ampersand for you... heh

Comment: If you still use SO, please mark a solution!

Comment: @Veedrac: How is this 4 year old question marked as a duplicate of a question asked 6 days ago?

Comment: @User Because the dupe has an accepted answer which is arguably more descriptive and explains the problem better than this one

Comment: It was decided on [chat] that the new question should be made canonical. Thus everything *else* is officially a dupe of it. Any disagreements should go to [Meta] for discussion.

Comment: I agree that the other question has a better title and a better answer, and in principle I prefer to favor the better question/answer; just went against how I understood stackoverflow to work.  I know I have asked "duplicates" that were better expressed and had better answers than the originals.

Comment: This is not duplicate at all

Comment: Nothing here actually answers the question adding backslashes without escaping. In C# I can @myfile and it is a literal whether a variable or fixed string. Python seems to have no such operator. r does not work with myfilename - which becomes rmyfilename.

Answer (score 71):

The result `'\\&'` is only displayed - actually the string is `\&`:

```
>>> str = '&'
>>> new_str = str.replace('&', '\&')
>>> new_str
'\\&'
>>> print new_str
\&
```

Try it in a shell.

Comment: Why is this not marked as solution?

Comment: The OP needs the literal string to be `'\&'` not `'\\&'`.

Answer (score 29):

The extra backslash is not actually added; it's just added by the `repr()` function to indicate that it's a literal backslash. The Python interpreter uses the `repr()` function (which calls `__repr__()` on the object) when the result of an expression needs to be printed:

```
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> print '\\'
\
>>> print '\\'.__repr__()
'\\'
```

Answer (score 25):

Python treats `\` in literal string in a special way.
This is so you can type `'\n'` to mean *newline* or `'\t'` to mean *tab*
Since `'\&'` doesn't mean anything special to Python, instead of causing an error, the Python lexical analyser implicitly adds the extra `\` for you.

Really it is better to use `\\&` or `r'\&'` instead of `'\&'`

The `r` here means *raw string* and means that `\` isn't treated specially unless it is right before the quote character at the start of the string.

In the interactive console, Python uses `repr` to display the result, so that is why you see the double '\'. If you `print` your string or use `len(string)` you will see that it is really only the 2 characters

Some examples

```
>>> 'Here\'s a backslash: \\'
"Here's a backslash: \\"
>>> print 'Here\'s a backslash: \\'
Here's a backslash: \
>>> 'Here\'s a backslash: \\. Here\'s a double quote: ".'
'Here\'s a backslash: \\. Here\'s a double quote: ".'
>>> print 'Here\'s a backslash: \\. Here\'s a double quote: ".'
Here's a backslash: \. Here's a double quote ".
```

To Clarify the point Peter makes in his comment see [this link](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

> Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized
>   escape sequences are left in the
>   string unchanged, i.e., the backslash
>   is left in the string. (This behavior
>   is useful when debugging: if an escape
>   sequence is mistyped, the resulting
>   output is more easily recognized as
>   broken.) It is also important to note
>   that the escape sequences marked as
>   “(Unicode only)” in the table above
>   fall into the category of unrecognized
>   escapes for non-Unicode string
>   literals.

Comment: Part of this isn't correct.  Python does *not* "implicitly add the extra `\` for you".  It does, however, double the backslash when you display the repr() output of the string, as at prompt, purely for presentation purposes.  len("\&") is only 2, proving there is no implicit munging of your data (thank heavens!).

Comment: @PeterHansen I think the OP was pointing out that blackslashes should normally be escaped in non-raw strings so it would normally be written doubled.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> '\\&' == '\&'
True
>>> len('\\&')
2
>>> print('\\&')
\&
```

Or in other words: `'\\&'` only contains one backslash. It's just escaped in the python shell's output for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

printing a list can also cause this problem (im new in python, so it confused me a bit too):

```
>>>myList = ['\\']
>>>print myList
['\\']
>>>print ''.join(myList)
\
```

similarly:

```
>>>myList = ['\&']
>>>print myList
['\\&']
>>>print ''.join(myList)
\&
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no extra backslash, it's just formatted that way in the interactive environment. Try:

```
print string
```

Then you can see that there really is no extra backslash.