# str.replace adding back slash

Tags: python

I have this interactive session:

```
>>> str = '192.168.1.1'
>>> str = str.replace('.','\.')
>>> str
'192\\.168\\.1\\.1'
```

I want the out put to be: `192\.168\.1\.1` instead of `192\\.168\\.1\\.1`

How can I achieve this? Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `print str` instead of `str`:

```
>> str = '192.168.1.1'
>>> str = str.replace('.','\.')
>>> str
'192\\.168\\.1\\.1'
>>> print str
192\.168\.1\.1
```

Your string is the one you expect it to be, but when you just dump the object, python is showing it to you in a form you could use to assign to another string - that means escaping the `\` characters.

Answer (score 3):

The string is exactly what it should be. The extra slashes are only in the display, not in the actual string.

Comment: The reason being, I suppose, that \. is not a valid escape sequence?

Answer (score 0):

\ is an escape character, so \ is required to add \ to the string by hiding its escape character nature.

If you use "print" before your string name, you'll see how it appears rather than what it actually contains.