# Escaping In Python 3.3.2 Special Character

Tags: python, escaping

I have not been able to figure this out this afternoon so I decided to ask. I am trying to generate some html code with a reference to Google Maps. My output file is a .csv and my delimeter is ;

Python keeps breaking up the Google Maps url line and putting it in another column. Here is the url string that needs to keep the raw &

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Phoenix+AZ&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=12&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=near&amp;output=embed
```

I need to preserve the `amp;` in that url line. I've tried several different codes but nothing has worked. Here is where the code is at in my script.

```
'<iframe width="425" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=' + line.split(",")[0]+"" + ' ' + line.split(",")[1]+"" + '&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=12&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=near&amp;output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>'
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to preserve the `amp;`? Your link seems broken to me (try it). I've just removed the `amp;` part, and actually got [your link working](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Phoenix+AZ&ie=UTF8&z=12&t=m&iwloc=near&output=embed). You can also substitute special characters in URLs with their ascci codes, prefixed by `%` (`&` --> `%26`). The `urllib`/`urllib2` module might help with encoding, too.

Comment: Your awesome! That's what the problem was. The maps are loading just fine now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

<s>To escape the ampersands, you need to replace the `&`s with `\&`s.  I see you tried to escape the ampersands with html character escapes, but that doesn't work the same way in Python.  Thus, you need to change `&amp;` into `\&`.</s>

[Adding backslashes without escaping [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python)

Sorry, I had a brain-fart and somehow thought that ampersands need to be escaped in Python, when they don't. :P

Comment: Right you are, but the link you get this way is still broken.