# In python when getting the current directory and replacing the spaces with escape charactor and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I was writing a python script which will take some data from sql server and then write to the current directory as excel. I am using pandas for it. And to get the current directory I am using package os

```
import os

def getCurrDir():
   return os.getcwd().replace(" ","\ ")
```

now when calling this function while writing a excel sheet like this

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(str(self.getCurrDir())+"/Temp_ID.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
temp.to_excel(writer,"Temp_ID_Data", index=False)
writer.save()
```

I am not able to write because the error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/srinath/Documents/Copy/Affine/workspace\\ python/Swipe/Temp_ID.xlsx'
```

One can see that the double slash is coming up. I thought that double slash is just for representation and I have learnt from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python) . So what is going on?
I am using python 3.4 from continuum. 
I am using centos 7 64 bit.

Comment: You don't need to use the directory name if you are reading/writing in the cwd, you just need to use the name of the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need escape the spaces in Python.

Define `getCurrDir()` as

```
def getCurrDir():
   return os.getcwd()
```

When you escape your spaces in Python with a backslash, Python then thinks your intended path has a backslash in it, and tries to handle the file access by adding *another* backslash to your backslash. Hence the invalid `workspace\\ python` file access attempt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and `os.getcwd` to create correct path:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Temp_ID.xlsx"), engine="xlsxwriter")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer that is definitely a clever way to handle :)