# How to make Python call to ignore special characters

Tags: python, special-characters

From Python3, I need to call application and pass it several arguments, one of which is

```
700x500\>
```

So I do this:

```
rule_template=r"{}x{}{}"
factor = r"\>"
rule = rule_template.format(700,500,factor)
cmd = ["mogrify", "-resize", rule]
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png"):
        ff = os.path.join(folder, file)
        subprocess.check_call(cmd + [ff])
```

And the application fails because the argument it recieves looks like

```
700x500\\>
```

How to avoid double slashes in the output. Again, it is not an "on screen only" feature, the application I call recieves wrong command.

Here is the [full](https://pastebin.com/PdKHeLKN) function that fails.

This is the error line:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mogrify', '-resize', '100x5\\>', '/tmp/111/de0b8660-b132-4874-b898-1ab4d4a24375/001.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

If I replace the "factor" variable with empty `""`, application works, but does not do what I need it to.

Application usage example:

```
mogrify -resize 100x5\> 001.jpg
```

Comment: There is only a single backslash in your `rule` variable, so that can't be the problem. As it is, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to escape the `>` with `\>` when you don't need to for the resize factor... just set factor to `>` as it'll already be escaped appropriately...

Comment: read more that this here: [adding backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python)

Comment: @Rawing The question only requires some familiarity with what `mogrify` expects as an argument to `-resize` to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you *don't* need the backslash. If you were calling this from the shell,

```
mogrify -resize 700x500\>
```

would be correct because the `>` needs to be escaped to prevent the shell from interpreting it as an output redirection character. However, you are (correctly) passing a list of separate arguments to `check_call`, bypassing the shell. `mogrify` itself just needs the string `700x500>`, so all you need is

```
rule_template = "{}x{}{}"
factor = ">"
rule = rule_template.format(700, 500, factor)
cmd = ["mogrify", "-resize", rule]
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png"):
        ff = os.path.join(folder, file)
        subprocess.check_call(cmd + [ff])
```

---

A specific example of a call to `check_call` would be

```
subprocess.check_call(["mogrify", "-resize", "700x500>", "foo.jpg"])
```

---

Completely unrelated, you only need one call to `endswith`, as it can take a tuple of expected extensinons:

```
if file.endswith((".jpg", ".png")):
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. ImageMagic manual I had contains lines with backslashes, so I was sure it expects "XxY\>" string as argument.

Comment: They were probably demonstrating actual command lines.  Quoting as `mogrify -resize "700x500>" ...` would also work in the shell.